# Deal with dates in R

Tags: r, date

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm trying to do something I'm sure is simple but I cannot figure out. I want to do a scatterplot in R with the date on the x-axis and relative frequency on the y-axis. Problem is, it all clusters on certain spots on the x-axis because R doesn't realize that the numbers are dates. The dates are formatted yearmonthset where set is the 0th or 1st or 2nd set of 10 days in that month. So 12071 is 2012 July 1st set. I need R to realize that there are 3 sets in a month and 12 months in a year and 4 years and space the scatterplot that way. What's the best way to solve this?

Here is a snippet of my data:

```
ID,Date,Trigram,Freq,Relfreq
TPN,12071,a constitutional convention,6,0.00001211467753757064371339095882
TPN,12111,a constitutional convention,2,0.000003302558987831721409334022467
TPN,11071,a constitutional convention,6,0.00001211467753757064371339095882
TPN,11111,a constitutional convention,2,0.000003302558987831721409334022467
TPN,10071,a constitutional convention,6,0.00001211467753757064371339095882
TPN,10111,a constitutional convention,2,0.000003302558987831721409334022467
TPN,09071,a constitutional convention,6,0.00001211467753757064371339095882
TPN,09111,a constitutional convention,2,0.000003302558987831721409334022467
CR,10032,a constitutional convention,3,0.000001049388049359016289650690200
CR,10062,a constitutional convention,2,7.020490002120187980640296770E-7
```

I tried to use as.date() as described on this site http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html but I don't really get it.

```
> strdates <- origina_NoCon$Date
> dates <- as.Date(strdates, %y%m)
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "dates <- as.Date(strdates, %y%"
```

**Edit:**

This is part of the output of dput(strdates):

```
> dput(strdates)
c(12071L, 12111L, 11071L, 11111L, 10071L, 10111L, 9071L, 9111L, 
10032L, 10062L, 11041L, 11071L, 11111L, 11121L, 12020L, 12021L, 
12102L, 12110L, 12111L, 11021L,...)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give the output of `dput(strdates)`. (This seems to be `character`s, but you'd need to recode if they are `factor`s.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa done! does this change your answer below? Thank you.

Comment: To a trivial degree. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first change your `strdates` to `character` by padding with zeros as necessary:

```
strdates.chr <- sprintf("%05i",strdates)
```

You can now first reformat them to represent the *first* of each month, then convert this to `Date`:

```
> as.Date(paste0(substr(strdates.chr,1,4),"01"),format="%y%m%d")
 [1] "2012-07-01" "2012-11-01" "2011-07-01" "2011-11-01" "2010-07-01"
 [6] "2010-11-01" "2009-07-01" "2009-11-01" "2010-03-01" "2010-06-01"
[11] "2011-04-01" "2011-07-01" "2011-11-01" "2011-12-01" "2012-02-01"
[16] "2012-02-01" "2012-10-01" "2012-11-01" "2012-11-01" "2011-02-01"
```

In order to then include the last piece of information, extract that (`substr`), convert to `numeric`, and finally add the appropriate multiple of 10 days (adding integers to `Date`s will automatically be interpreted as adding a number of days):

```
> as.Date(paste0(substr(strdates.chr,1,4),"01"),format="%y%m%d")+
+ as.numeric(substr(strdates.chr,5,5))*10
 [1] "2012-07-11" "2012-11-11" "2011-07-11" "2011-11-11" "2010-07-11"
 [6] "2010-11-11" "2009-07-11" "2009-11-11" "2010-03-21" "2010-06-21"
[11] "2011-04-11" "2011-07-11" "2011-11-11" "2011-12-11" "2012-02-01"
[16] "2012-02-11" "2012-10-21" "2012-11-01" "2012-11-11" "2011-02-11"
```

Comment: Iigh thank you for your help but now I get this as the output:  dput(date)
structure(c(15522, 15645, 15156, 15279, 14791, 14914, 14426, 
14549, 14679, 14771, 15065, 15156, 15279, 15309, 15361, 15371, 
15624, 15635, 15645, 15006, 15258, 15279, 14631, 14641, 14781, 
14873, 14893, 14914, 14266, 14276, 14416, 14508, 14528, 14549...)

Comment: Yes, but with `class = "Date"` at the very end. `Date`s are internally represented as integers, namely the offset in days from the "UNIX beginning of time", namely 1970-01-01. Your vector `date` should still do what you need. Look at `print(date)`.

Comment: Oh I get it! Thank you so much for your patience. But I'm still a little confused. Now it says everything was done on the first day of the month. how do I have it add the appropriate multiple of 10 days based on the "0" or "1" or "2" at the end of the string of characters?

Comment: That should be taken care of. Use the *second* code block in my answer. The second line there does the adding. The results I pasted show a couple of "11" or "21" days-of-month.

Comment: ah yes perfect thank you!! Sorry I'd made a small mistake in using the second line.